# How i can use in my data provider MAX() and WHERE?

Tags: genexus

i need to return my max pedcod number that have peduf = "SP".

I try:

```
Tpedpro
where peduf = "SP"
max(pedcod)
{
    Pedcod = Pedcod + 1
}
```

Tpedpro is my transaction table.
But i receive:

> error src0110: Missing group start brace '{'
>   error src0115: Invalid expression after group definition; are you
>   trying to define a subgroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a DataProvider to get that value.
Just use an inline formula for example in the source of a procedure:

```
&MaxPedCod = max(PedCod, peduf = !"SP")
```

---

If you really want to use a DataProvider, you may write this:

```
Tpedpro [one]
order (pedcod)
where peduf = "SP"
{
    Pedcod = Pedcod + 1
}
```

that would mean: get the first record where `peduf = "SP"` with descending order by `pedcod`

Comment: thanks, the first option work for me, i really don't need an dataProvider.